# Is it possible to apply css to an element based on the class of dynamically generated element?

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="first">
    <div class="a">
        <div class="b">
            <div class="c">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="first">
    <div class="one">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to style `div` with `class="first"`(i.e,(2) from above) if there is a `div` with `class="c"`.

Context: Here the `div` with `class="c"` will be dynamically generated,so if this `div` exits i want to apply css for `div` with `class="first"`(i.e,(2) from above).
What could be the css rule for the above case?

Comment: Based on child element you can't target parent in CSS. You have to use javascript or jquery to achieve this. Simply there is no parent selector in CSS.

Comment: how can i achieve this in jquery?

Comment: @ShashikanthBuddhiol my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use jQuery.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.c').parents('.first').addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
/* DEMO */

div {
  padding: 1em;
  background: green;
  border: solid 1px;
}
div:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: yellow;
}
/* ADDED CLASS */

div.selected {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first">
  <div class="a">
    <div class="b">
      <div class="c">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="first">
  <div class="one">
  </div>
</div>
```